# SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type lombok

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok

I am getting below error.

```
SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [com.xxxx.entity.Employee]
Reported exception:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.isValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:295)
    at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:329)
    at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(ChronoField.java:722)
    at java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(LocalDate.java:341)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(LocalDateTime.java:422)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$InstantPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:3194)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2179)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1746)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1720)
    at java.time.Instant.toString(Instant.java:1330)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.AuditEnabledEntity.toString(AuditEnabledEntity.java:25)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Department.toString(Department.java:38)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Employee.toString(Employee.java:30)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Department.toString(Department.java:38)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Employee.toString(Employee.java:30)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Department.toString(Department.java:38)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Employee.toString(Employee.java:30)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Department.toString(Department.java:38)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.xxxx.entity.Employee.toString(Employee.java:30)
```

AuditEnabledEntity.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AuditEnabledEntity {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "lastUpdateDate", nullable = false)
    private Instant lastUpdateDate;

    @Column(name = "createUser", nullable = false, length = IConst.USER_LENGTH)
    private String createUser;

    @Column(lastUpdateUser)
    private String lastUpdateUser;
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Employee extends AuditEnabledEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private Integer id;

    .......
    .......
    .......

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "program_member_program", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false, updatable = false}, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id", nullable = false, updatable = false})
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Department> departments;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "programMembers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

Department.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper=true, includeFieldNames=true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name="department_name_key",columnNames = {"department_name"})
})
public class Department extends AuditEnabledEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "department_id")
    private Long departmentId;

    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....

    // bi-directional
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="employees", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Department> departments;
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/57238957/10961238

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a bidirectional reference between `Employee` (via field `departments`) and `Department` (we cannot see which field because you omitted that, or your pasted code is wrong). Both generated `toString()` methods in these classes call each other endlessly.

Exclude one of these fields for the generated `toString()` (preferably the field that is less important) using `@ToString.Exclude`.

PS: You will probably run into a similar problem for `equals` and `hashCode`. Exclude it there too using `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`.

Comment: I can't simply omit references between `Employee` & `Department`. Also, not good practice to removed `Equals & Hashcode` when dealing with collections. Could you please show some code to fix this issue ?

Comment: You should not omit one of the fields, you should just skip it for the Lombok-generated `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override toString method instead of lombok annotation